# Selecting random rows while maintaining proportions of original data distribution?

Tags: r, data.table

Consider I have the following data.table

```
d <- data.table(group=rep(letters[1:5],c(30,20,20,20,10)), x=1:100, y=101:201)
```

which represents data for 5 groups which are distributed as

```
d[,.N,by=group]
```

Now, how do I select a small sample, let's say 10 rows (or 10% of the data) which has, roughly, similar group distribution based on one or more columns.  So, for the above table a hypothetical subset that I could receive would be something like:

```
  group   x    y
   a      8  108
   b     32  132
   e     93  193
   b     46  146
   d     88  188
   c     53  153
   c     68  168
   a     19  119
   d     74  174
   a     24  124
```

How do I do this in, preferably, data.table?  There's a question on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835850/selecting-rows-maintaining-distribution-percentage) that discusses this but I'd rather not calculate distribution percentages manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should use `caret`. The `createDataPartition()` function is meant to subset a dataset without losing the probability distribution of your target variable.

```
library(caret)
my.ids <- createDataPartition(d$group, p = 0.1)
train <- d[as.numeric(my.ids[[1]]), ]
```

You can check the distribution of your target variable in the population and in your subset.

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
barplot(table(d$group), main = "full dataset")
barplot(table(train$group), main = "subset")
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice!  Thank you Damiano, for pointing out `caret::createDataPartition` and a thorough answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can sample the *index/row_number* `.I` by group and then subset the original data table with it:

```
d[d[, sample(.I, .N * 0.1), group]$V1]

#    group   x   y
# 1:     a  10 110
# 2:     a   2 102
# 3:     a  14 114
# 4:     b  45 145
# 5:     b  49 149
# 6:     c  62 162
# 7:     c  51 151
# 8:     d  84 184
# 9:     d  76 176
#10:     e 100 200
```

Here `.I` is an integer vector representing the global row number, i.e, `seq_len(nrow(d))`, `d[, sample(.I, .N * 0.1), group]` with then take a proportion of the row numbers from each group, subset the original data.table with the index (unnamed column default to `V1`) gives what you need.

Comment: Or `d[sample(.N), head(.SD, .N*.1), by=group]` (jumble all rows then select top).

Comment: @Frank Nice one.

Comment: Thank you Psidom and Frank !  Thanks @Frank for also fixing the question formatting.  Much appreciated.